# How do i get all current running process id in Android 8 and above

Tags: android

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService("usagestats");
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            List<UsageStats> appListO = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 1000, time);
            if (appListO != null && appListO.size() > 0) {
                for (UsageStats usageStats : appListO) {
                    Integer PID1= ? 
                 
                    unSortedMap.put(usageStats.getPackageName(), getUsage(PID1));

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ActivityService` to fetch the all running process in android

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<runningappprocessinfo> runningProcesses = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

Comment: Thanks @mdroid, I tried this method, it only gives my application process details. I want all running process details.

Comment: Hey @Shruti, look out this example, it might be helpful for you.
https://github.com/ColeMurray/UsageStatsSample

Comment: UsageStats is not returning process id, first i tried that only. I need process id of all running application